# Why connect the gate of a MOSFET to ground?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, schematics

I was looking through the schematic for the [Teensy 4.0](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy40.html), and I found that a transistor that sends power to the microcontroller for operating the usb connector has its gate connected to ground. This seems to make the transistor act as a diode, but I am confused as to why a diode wasn't used in this case.

Is there a reason a transistor was used instead of a diode?

Below are the links to the schematic/relevant parts and an image of the portion of the schematic I am talking about:

[Schematic](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/schematic.html)
[Transistor datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2305UX.pdf)
[Microcontroller datasheet](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/MIMXRT1061CVJ5A.pdf)
[image: Image containing the transistor]

Comment: What DKN said. When input polarity is correct the body diode conducts (in the direction of the arrow) **AND** the FET is biased on as the gate is more negative that the source (= on-bias for a PFET). If the Vin is of reversed ploarity the body diode blocks **AND** the PFET is biased off. A series diode would produce the same protective result BUT in circuits where the diode voltage drop is unacceptable this allows almost zero voltage drop with a suitably low Rdson FET.  | ...

Comment: ... See datasheet fig 1 [here](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMG2305UX.pdf) - at say 1A Vdrop = is well under 0.1 V. (52 milliohm  Rdson typ)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is for reverse-polarity protection. It behaves *almost* like a diode but with very low voltage drop.

What is missing from that schematic symbol of a PMOS is the body diode which points from left to right. If the voltage at the source is positive relative to the gate the PMOS (initially facilitaed by the body diode conducting) then the PMOS turns on and the voltage drop across the source-drain falls to even lower than the forward drop of the diode.

But note that this isn't quite like a real diode. A real diode will stop current flow even if you connect a battery on the right side. This PMOS will not since the only thing required for it to conduct is that the source terminal voltage be more positive than the gate terminal voltage, which a load sending power back toward the supply can do (i.e. capacitors during shutdown of the power supply).

Answer (score 0):

The voltage drop on mosfet is lower than voltage drop of diode, if the drain source resistance of mosfet is low.

Answer (score -5):

At very high switching speeds a single current peak may produce a component damaging high reverse voltage in the order of tenths of volts surpassing the  max reverse voltage of most components in a low voltage circuitry.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I think you could improve this answer by expanding it some more. It's not clear what you're point is.